# How do you perform `push` on a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

What I am trying to achieve is use `push()` on a **JavaScript object**, that looks like so:

```
var apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ]
}
```

The goal is to add a third key "**demo**" to the object and then push another three lines to it.
So after all the pushing, the object should look like this:

```
var apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
    demo:
    [
        "ci-google",
        "My demo app!",
        "Some content"
    ]
}
```

### What I tried?

I tried the following piece of code `Object.keys(apps).push("demo");` (if this makes any sense). As an output, I just got **3** and the key "demo" was not added to the object.
And then to add items into *demo* I tried using this tiny piece of code
`Object.keys(apps)["demo"].push("blah blah blah...");`, but it totally did not work.

---

My brain and thoughts got obfuscated. Any help would be highly appreciated and very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `apps.demo = [...]`?!

Comment: @AndrewLi the point is to explain and help them understand, not just to fix their code

Comment: @DuncanThacker That's exactly why I commented, and didn't answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `push()` here, that's for adding to an exising array. You just want to add a key. The easiest way is like this:

```
apps.demo = [ "ci-google", "My demo app!", "Some content" ];
```

Or, equivalently

```
apps["demo"] = [ "ci-google", "My demo app!", "Some content" ];
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because `Object.keys( apps )` creates you a new array containing all the keys in the `apps` object, but doing stuff to that array doesn't do anything to the actual `apps` object - you're just editing your new array. What you need to do is change the apps object directly (as I've shown above).

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Can I just ask for an advice on how to replace "demo" with a variable in `apps["demo"]`? I tried `var id = "demo"; apps[id] = [...]` but I got the following error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [**

Comment: Hmm, that should work fine - can you post a bit more of your code?

Comment: That's all. It is put in an `else`, and then I run a function `_load()` to update an `<ul>` of the object values

Comment: I'm a bit stuck then, sorry. The bit you posted looks fine.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hYpreqv5 - this is the entire `if` statement. I've got some form validating

Comment: You've got `apps.[id]` instead of `apps[id]`.

Comment: Thank you. I was never going to see that

Comment: No problem. I strongly recommend using a static code checker like eslint to help spot errors - if you install the plugin in your IDE it will automatically highlight these errors and help you fix them. Let me know if you want more info and I'll help you get set up.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Duncan's answer has the lowest learning curve.

With that said - especially since you are already using the `.keys()` method on the built-in Object type - two options you can look into are:

1. [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
2. [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Both methods will return new objects with properties included that you pass as the second argument to the function.

`Object.assign(demo, {new_property})` will return an object with demo's *own* properties - thereby, neglecting the prototype chain.

`Object.create(demo, {new_property})` will return an object that is [prototype linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) to demo.